# Could not connect to postgres server in a docker from a dockerized app

Tags: django, postgresql, docker

I would like to run a dockerized Django app with a dockerized postgres.

I run the dockerized Django app by using:

```
docker run --rm --env-file /path/to/variables -d -p 8000:8000 django_app:test
```

I run a dockerized postgres by using:

```
docker run --rm -d --env-file /path/to/secrets/variables -p 5432:5432 \
    -v "$PWD/my-postgres.conf":/etc/postgresql/postgresql.conf \
    --mount src=/path/to/db/data,dst=/var/lib/postgresql/data,type=bind \
    postgres:alpine -c 'config_file=/etc/postgresql/postgresql.conf'
```

my postgres config is the default config that is suggested in the [postgres docker container documentation](https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres/). It is essentially a config file that contains `listen_addresses = '*'`

I use the **same** environment variables for both containers:

```
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=settings.module
PROJECT_KEY=xxyyzzabcdefg
DB_ENGINE=django.db.backends.postgresql
POSTGRES_DB=db_name
POSTGRES_USER=db_user
POSTGRES_PASSWORD=verydifficultpassword
POSTGRES_HOST=localhost # I've also tried to use 0.0.0.0
POSTGRES_PORT=5432
```

My Django settings module for the database is:

```
 DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': os.environ.get('DB_ENGINE'),
        'NAME': os.environ.get('POSTGRES_DB'),
        'USER': os.environ.get('POSTGRES_USER'),
        'PASSWORD': os.environ.get('POSTGRES_PASSWORD'),
        'HOST': os.environ.get('POSTGRES_HOST'),
        'PORT': os.environ.get('POSTGRES_PORT')
        }
  }
```

However, I keep on getting:

```
django.db.utils.OperationalError: could not connect to server: Connection refused
    Is the server running on host "0.0.0.0" and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

The Dockerfiles for my django app looks like:

```
FROM python:alpine3.7
COPY --from=installer /app /app
# required for postgres
COPY --from=installer /usr/lib /usr/lib
COPY --from=installer /usr/local/bin /usr/local/bin
COPY --from=installer /usr/local/lib /usr/local/lib
ARG SETTINGS_MODULE
WORKDIR /app
ENTRYPOINT python manage.py migrate &&\
           python manage.py test &&\
           python manage.py create_default_groups &&\
           python manage.py set_screen_permissions &&\
           python manage.py create_test_users &&\
           python manage.py init_core &&\
           python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

Another interesting fact is that if I run the app locally `python manage.py runserver` and have the postgres container running, the app seems to be working.

Can anyone help me try to figure out why am I getting a connection refused? Thanks in advance!

Comment: you guys gave (almost) the same answer at the same time. Sorry had to pick one =( ty for clarifying the network command =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make use of user-defined bridge networking. First, leverage your knowledge with reading a short explanation of different types of networks in Docker: https://docs.docker.com/network/bridge/

Second, define your own network

```
docker network create foo
```

Next, run your containers **connected** to this network:

```
docker run --rm --env-file /path/to/variables -d --network foo django_app:test
docker run --rm -d ... --network foo postgres:alpine ...
```

Notice in both commands `--network foo`. Also you **dont need** to expose ports in this case - inside user-defined networks it is done automatically:

> Containers connected to the same user-defined bridge network
>   automatically expose all ports to each other, and no ports to the
>   outside world. This allows containerized applications to communicate
>   with each other easily, without accidentally opening access to the
>   outside world.

Third, give your containers human readable host names with `--name bar`

```
docker run ... --network foo --name my-django django_app:test ...
docker run ... --network foo --name my-postgres postgres:alpine ...
```

And finally fix the connection string - change from `localhost` to container name, like `my-postgres`:

```
...
POSTGRES_HOST=my-postgres
...
```

Answer (score 1):

In your docker container with Django there is no Postgres running on localhost. you need to point to the Postgres docker container by specifying the **container name instead of localhost**
Also, the Postgres container and your app have to be in the same network. see https://docs.docker.com/network/

To create a network run:

```
docker network create --driver bridge my-network
```

To run docker container in the network use:

```
docker run --network my-network -it container_name
```

To setup Postgres in container with Django:

```
POSTGRES_HOST=postgres-container-name
```

Answer (score 0):

***In your case you are not specifying the container names. When setting `POSTGRES_HOST=localhost` you're telling the django container to connect to itself. Which is naturally going to fail as there is no postgres server present in the django container.***

Your two containers are using the default `bridge` network (docker0). In a bridge network the container names are used as host names.

This means means that from your `django` container you can access the `postgres` container by using its name as the hostname.

To be able to connect to postgres from you django app you need to:

1. Give names to your containers by using the `--name option`. Example: `docker run --rm --name mypostgresdb -d ... postgres:alpine -c ...`
2. First create the postgres container and wait for it to boot. Then create the database and user/password.
3. Only when postgres is up, create the django container. If the postgres container is not up your django container will fail since it's trying to run migrations in the ***entrypoint***.
4. The `POSTGRES_HOST` env variable in your django container should receive the **postgres** container's name as a value. Example: `POSTGRES_HOST=mypostgresdb`

To check the connection to you postgres container you can ping it from your django container.