# Python application cannot connect to PostgreSQL Docker

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

Can anyone help me on this?

**Dockerfile** for my image:

```
FROM python:3.6.1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
RUN mkdir /hlcup
WORKDIR /hlcup
ADD requirements.txt /hlcup/
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt
ADD . /hlcup/
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 5432
```

My **docker-compose.yml**:

```
version: '3'

services:
db:
    image: postgres
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: ${POSTGRES_USER}
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ${POSTGRES_PASSWORD}
      POSTGRES_DB: ${POSTGRES_DB}
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
  web:
    build: .
    command: python3 main.py
    volumes:
      - .:/hlcup
      - ./data:/tmp/data/
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    depends_on:
      - db
```

I run my build: **docker-compose up --build**

As a result, the application should connect to the database, but I get a connection error:

```
web_1  |     conn = await asyncpg.connect(**DB_PARAMS)
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/asyncpg/connection.py", line 1688, in connect
web_1  |     max_cacheable_statement_size=max_cacheable_statement_size)
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/asyncpg/connect_utils.py", line 551, in _connect
web_1  |     raise last_error
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/asyncpg/connect_utils.py", line 543, in _connect
web_1  |     connection_class=connection_class)
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/asyncpg/connect_utils.py", line 513, in _connect_addr
web_1  |     connector, timeout=timeout, loop=loop)
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/asyncio/tasks.py", line 352, in wait_for
web_1  |     return fut.result()
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/asyncio/base_events.py", line 776, in create_connection
web_1  |     raise exceptions[0]
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/asyncio/base_events.py", line 763, in create_connection
web_1  |     yield from self.sock_connect(sock, address)
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/asyncio/selector_events.py", line 451, in sock_connect
web_1  |     return (yield from fut)
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/asyncio/selector_events.py", line 481, in _sock_connect_cb
web_1  |     raise OSError(err, 'Connect call failed %s' % (address,))
web_1  | ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connect call failed ('0.0.0.0', 5432)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Could not connect to postgres server in a docker from a dockerized app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53969865/could-not-connect-to-postgres-server-in-a-docker-from-a-dockerized-app)

Comment: Short answer: configure your application (preferably using an environment variable) to connect to the other Docker Compose service name `db` as a host name.  `localhost` means "this container", and on Linux outbound connections to 0.0.0.0 (which isn't a "real" IP address) also go to `localhost`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You container `web` is tries to connecting to database with local ip `0.0.0.0:5432` and the database is on other container with another ip.

docker-compose support DNS between container, so I would try change in the python app from an ip number to a DNS.

In your docker-compose file, the postgres database DNS is `db`